# Postgres 11.9 DB benchmark

Tags: postgresql-11

I am trying to benchmark the PostgresDB on a Redhat Linux OS VM with 4 core CPU and 16GB mem.

using this documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgbench.html

The Transcation can be a set of sql statements.

Below are test results

```
Test 1

1 Transaction is 1- Query, 1 – insert , 3 -updates

scaling factor: 10
query mode: simple
number of clients: 10
number of threads: 2
number of transactions per client: 10000
number of transactions actually processed: 100000/100000
latency average = 105.812 ms
tps = 94.507634 (including connections establishing)
tps = 94.507961 (excluding connections establishing)

scaling factor: 10
query mode: simple
number of clients: 4
number of threads: 2
number of transactions per client: 10000
number of transactions actually processed: 40000/40000
latency average = 15.667 ms
tps = 255.315579 (including connections establishing)
tps = 255.321942 (excluding connections establishing)

Test 2

1 Transaction is 1- Query , 1 – update , 1- insert

scaling factor: 10
query mode: simple
number of clients: 10
number of threads: 2
number of transactions per client: 10000
number of transactions actually processed: 100000/100000
latency average = 87.134 ms
tps = 114.766068 (including connections establishing)
tps = 114.766546 (excluding connections establishing)

scaling factor: 10
query mode: simple
number of clients: 4
number of threads: 2
number of transactions per client: 10000
number of transactions actually processed: 40000/40000
latency average = 13.067 ms
tps = 306.121787 (including connections establishing)
tps = 306.131759 (excluding connections establishing)
```

How do we intrepret these above results.

We are looking if postgres is capable of handling 5000TPS. 1TPS(2 simple query with primary key + 2 update(insert)).

Comment: What if you run it with more clients? e.g. 100 and maybe 8 threads?

Comment: As per pgbench documentation. threads should be the equal or less than cpu and clients can be multiple size of cpu.

Comment: The point is: do you get more TPS if you increase the number of clients/threads?